# Use of DATE_TRUNC FUNCTION

Tags: sorting, date

Does the DATE_TRUNC FUNCTION allows You to solve the problem concerning counting the number of days events per a day during the last 30 days?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Just one question: are you using Postgres as your database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - assuming you are using Postgres - you can use that function to extract date parts and then group and count an event for each specific day.

In the following example I have a table `tb_registration` with a `date` timestamp column and I use the `DATE_TRUNC` function to group by day, month, year. I also apply in this example a filter for a certain number of days to the `date` column.

```
select date_part('day', DATE_TRUNC('day', date)) "day", 
  date_part('month', DATE_TRUNC('month', date)) "month", 
  date_part('year', DATE_TRUNC('year', date)), count(*) "year"
    from tb_registration where date > NOW() - INTERVAL '600 days'
      group by DATE_TRUNC('day', date), 
        DATE_TRUNC('month', date), 
        DATE_TRUNC('year', date) order by 3 desc, 2 desc, 1 desc
```

This query produces the following results:

```
14;4;2017;1
11;4;2017;90
10;4;2017;99
9;4;2017;60
8;4;2017;66
7;4;2017;83
6;4;2017;87
5;4;2017;76
4;4;2017;91
3;4;2017;110
2;4;2017;52
1;4;2017;46
31;3;2017;66
```

Where the columns are:

1. day
2. month
3. year
4. count